# Interpreting Dickey-Fuller test vs Autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have time series dataset and I have run the Augmented Dickey–Fuller test using statsmodels and got the below statistic

```
ADF Statistic: -4.031907
p-value: 0.001252
Critical Values:
    1%: -3.434
    5%: -2.863
    10%: -2.568
```

Comparing with the tests critical values, I can reject the Null hypothesis that the data is not stationary. Which means my time series data is stationary

I have run the pandas autocorrelation plot which shows autocorrelation in the time series dataset.[image]

Which means that there is non-stationarity in the data.

Which contradicts the conclusion from Dickey-Fuller test.

Is my understanding of both these approaches correct or am i missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Autocorrelation is not samething as non-stationarity. it is good to have autocorellation in your data as you will have predictive power because of it.